# Is there a simple argument why graph isomorphism is not NP-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete

I need to provide one simple evidence that graph isomorphism (GI) is not NP-complete.

I saw a number of papers on google scholar and answers on StackExchange. However, I have very limited knowledge of graph isomorphism, and I would like to just provide one simple evidence which I both understand and can explain clearly.

---

Below is what I can think of. Is this a valid argument?

Currently, we can solve GI in Quasipolynomial Time. If GI is NP-complete, then we should be able to solve other NP-complete problems in Quasipolynomial Time as well. However, right now, we are unable to solve any NP-complete problem in Quasipolynomial Time. Therefore, GI cannot be in np-complete.

Comment: "Nobody knows how" (to solve any NP-complete problem "feasibly") sounds flaky when I think *proof*.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem) has an explanation which doesn't require Babai's new algorithm: if graph isomorphism is NP-complete, then the polynomial hierarchy collapses.

Comment: Your explanation is also good: if graph isomorphism is NP-complete, then [ETH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis) is false.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The type of argument you are looking for is as follows:

> If graph isomorphism were NP-complete, then some widely believed complexity assumption fails.

There are at least two such arguments:

1. [Schöning](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022000088900104) showed that if graph isomorphism is NP-complete then the [polynomial hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_hierarchy) collapses to the second level (equivalently, $\Sigma_2^P = \Pi_2^P$).
2. [Babai's quasipolynomial time algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03547) implies that if graph isomorphism is NP-complete then the [exponential time hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis) fails.

Whether such arguments are "valid" or not is a sociological question, not a mathematical one.

Comment: For a non-specialist (me): "the polynomial hierarchy collapses" means P=NP?
Then, if understood this correctly, for the OP it seems beneficial to state explicitly that we do not know whether graph isomorphism is NP-complete, but we do know that if graph isomorphism is NP-complete then P=NP, which is thought to be false. We even know that it would imply ETH which in turn is known to imply P=NP, but not the other way around.

Comment: No, the polynomial hierarchy collapses does not mean that P=NP. In this case it means that $\Sigma_2^P = \Pi_2^P$.

Comment: Ok, thanks! As I said, I do not know this stuff...